# create_function pode ser um risco para o meu código?

Tags: php, expressões-lambda

O PHP a partir da versão `5.3` passou a implementar o recurso chamado `funções anônimas` ou `Closure`.

O seu uso se dá dessa maneira:

```
$sort = function ($a, $b) { return $a - $b; };
$array = [1, 3, 2];
usort($array, $sort);
```

Porém, quando se trata das versões anteriores, não temos um recurso desse tipo, sendo necessário usar dois possíveis recursos alterativos:

- Criar funções inicializadas por `_` para identificar que a mesma é "temporária" ou é apenas para callback.

Exemplo:

```
function _sort($a, $b)
{
   return $a - $b;
}

usort($array, '_sort');
```

- Usar a função `create_function`.

Exemplo:

```
$lambda = create_function('$a, $b', 'return $a-$b;');
usort($array, $lambda);
```

Nesse último caso, entra o meu questionamento, pois **essa função usa `eval` internalmente**. E isso está no manual.

Exemplo:

```
create_function('', 'ERRO_DE_SINTAXE_DE_PROPOSITO')
```

Saída será:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in phar:///usr/local/bin/psysh/src/Psy/ExecutionLoop/Loop.php(76) : 
>     eval()'d code(1) : runtime-created function on line 1

Sendo assim, por conta de utilizar o `eval` internamente, o seu uso é recomendável? Ou, em caso de versões que não exista `Closure`,  devo usar a função com o underline antes?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `create_function`, contudo precisa evitar os casos de uso problemáticos dela. Primeiramente, como essa função utiliza `eval` internamente, é **muito importante**  que não passe nenhum dado inserido pelo usuário, exemplo:

```
$x = $_POST['user_input'];
$lambda = create_function('', 'return "O usuário digitou: ' . $x . '";');
```

Fazendo algo como no caso acima você, deixa um brecha para alguém executar código arbitrário no seu sistema. Vai se dar mal!

Fora o problema de segurança clássico de `eval`, `create_function` tem mais um caso com que você deve ficar atento, segundo a própria documentação a função `has bad performance and memory usage characteristics`. Então você, definitivamente, não vai querer invocar ela dentro de um trecho de código muito usado no seus sistema - um laço ou um método central que vários outros método usam por exemplo.

Como eu escrevi antes, você pode usar a função, mas tem que ficar se policiando (e os seus colegas ;]) para não gerar um problema de segurança, de performance ou vazamento de memória.

Como todo mundo eventualmente erra uma hora, basta você fazer a mesma coisa um número suficiente de vezes. É, provavelmente, mais sensato ficar longe dela e se ater à sua convenção de prefixar funções temporárias com `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Do meu ponto de vista a premissa do uso de `eval()` e `create_function()` é basicamente o mesmo do que já respondi em:

- [Por que dizem que o $_GET no PHP é inseguro contra sql injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188306/3635)

A insegurança esta em expor ao usuário o uso disto, ou até mesmo expor entrada de dados variantes do qual você não tem controle total, por exemplo:

```
$data = $_GET['data'];

$foo = create_function('$arg', "return $data == $y;");

echo $foo;
```

Então o usuário inseri algo como na URL:

```
http://site.com/foo.php?data=print_r%28%24_SESSION%29
```

Então seria processado gerado algo como em `$foo`:

```
function () {
     return print_r($_SESSION) == $arg;
}
```

Desta forma alguém mal intencionado poderia exibir todos dados de sessão sensíveis. Outro exemplo de expor os dados possivelmente sensíveis:

```
http://site.com/foo.php?data=var_dum%28pget_defined_constants%28%true%29%,get_defined_vars%28%%29%
```

Então seria processado gerado algo como em `$foo`:

```
function () {
     return var_dump(get_defined_constants(true), get_defined_vars()) == $arg;
}
```

Em todos casos o problema é a exposição da entrada de dados e não com as funções em si.

---

### Porque não usar create_function

Independente da questão de segurança o uso de `create_function` esta em desuso desde o php7.2:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php
>
> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

isto porque para a maioria dos casos uma função lambda/Closure já resolve tudo e para os dados mais complexos uma string pode se comportar com parte da linguagem provavelmente `eval` vai resolver (o que raramente é necessário, talvez para um sistema de **macro** seria útil)