# Por que dizem que o $_GET no PHP é inseguro contra sql injection?

Tags: php, sql-injection

Bom, a minha dúvida, é simples.

Tenho andado ultimamente, a ouvir muitas histórias a dizer que o $_GET no PHP é inseguro contra sql injection.

Poderiam-me dizer porquê?

Comment: Você pode deixar uma porta aberta para um ataque SQL-Injection que nada mais é do que a inserção de um código SQL em um parâmetro da URL que será enviado diretamente para o banco

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Não é o `$_GET` que é inseguro, o problema é como usa ele.

Os dados podem vir por `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE` ou até uma string gravada previamente em um arquivo e posteriormente adicionada a execução de uma query.

O problema está em como passar diretamente os valores na query (concatenando na string), por exemplo:

```php
"SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nome LIKE '%{$_GET['nome']}%'"
```

Desta forma seria possível fazer algo como `http://site/pagina.php?nome=';QUERY` e geraria isto:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nome LIKE '';QUERY'
```

Claro que no caso acima no máximo obteria uma falha de sintaxe, no geral a API não permite múltiplas queries, agora imagine que os dados de uma SELECT são baseados em um id salvo na sessão e os produtos que o usuário pode visualizar em um painel são somente os com a ID (`id_dono`) dele:

```php
"SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto={$_GET['idproduto']} AND id_dono={$_SESSION['idautenticado']}"
```

Mas se digitar isso acessar isto `http://site/pagina.php?idproduto=6 --` e geraria isto:

```sql
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto=6 -- AND id_dono=5
```

Desta maneira o usuário ignorou tudo que vier depois de `--` e pode obter os dados privados de produtos de outros usuários em um suposto painel aonde controlaria os seus produtos.

Outro exemplo seria manipular qualquer coluna de uma tabela:

```php
"UPDATE dados SET nome='%{$_GET['nome']}%' WHERE id={$_GET['id']}"
```

Suponhamos que temos colunas que não deveria poder ser alteradas, mas se você fizer algo como `http://site/pagina.php?id=1&nome=',outracoluna='xxxxxx` você irá ter controle sobre qualquer coluna da tabela, pois vai gerar algo como:

```sql
UPDATE dados SET nome='',outracoluna='xxxxxx' WHERE id=1
```

Leia isto de como evitar:

- [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/3635)

Um exemplo simples é usar o `bindValue` ou `bindParam`:

`PDO`+`bindValue`:

```php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost dbname=teste', 'usuario', 'senha');
    
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nome LIKE ?');

$stmt->bindValue(1, '%' . $_GET['busca'] . '%'); // passado diretamente

$stmt->execute();
```

`PDO`+`bindParam`:

```php
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nome LIKE :consulta');

$stmt->bindParam(':consulta', $nome);

$nome = '%' . $_GET['consulta'] . '%';
```

`Mysqli`+`bind_param`:

> mysqli só trabalha com `bind_param`, ou seja **não** existe um `bind_value`

```php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'teste');

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nome LIKE ?');

if(!$stmt){
    echo 'erro na consulta: '. $db->errno .' - '. $db->error;
} else {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $nome);

    $nome = '%' . $_GET['consulta'] . '%';

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

### bindValue e bindParam

- `bindParam` trabalha com referencias, ou seja só deve-se usar variáveis e constantes. Se for uma variável o valor pode ser alterado posteriormente, mas antes do `execute`
- `bindValue` trabalha com qualquer tipo de valor, variável constante ou passado diretamente

Leia mais em: [Qual a diferença entre bindParam e bindValue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87384/3635)

Comment: Concretamente o que faz o bindValue?

Comment: @Gonçalo muitas destas duvidas já tem resposta no site, de qualquer forma adicionei a resposta.

Comment: Excelente resposta, Obrigado!