# Importâncias do bind no PHP e outras linguagens

Tags: php, query, segurança

Segurança e performance é algo extremamente importante para qualquer aplicação, sendo assim utiliza-se algumas técnicas para o desenvolvimento.

Uma delas é o `bind` para realizar qualquer tipo de query em seu banco de dados.

Quando você faz por exemplo:

```
 $CEP->nomeBairro($nomeBairro);
 $CEP->inserirCepAtendido();
```

e na sua classe você tem um insert com `bindParam`, sei que esse tipo de parametrização é extremamente vantajoso na questão segurança.

Me bateu uma curiosidade, essa abordagem, tem como benefício apenas segurança ou outros benefícios?

Comment: Outra vantagem seria não precisar misturar as variaveis ou valores (bindValue) no meio da query, mas é relativo o quanto isso é vantagem, de resto é só um facilitador pra evitar ter que fazer as coisas "remendadas" no meio, o teu código ali pra mim não faz sentido, nem OO faz muito sentido em PHP, a maioria usa pq acha bonito e não por necessidade real, mas nem vou entrar neste mérito de debate, o ponto que quero levantar são: ["segurança"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188306/3635), não é bem que não era segurança, mas de segurança de como muitas vezes usavam errado ...

Comment: ... e este [comentário do @bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302/mysqli-vs-pdo-qual-o-mais-recomendado-para-usar#comment52899_8338)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Junto com a segurança (prevenção de ataques de injeção e outros erros) ele é um facilitador para colocar o valor na *query* sem misturar as coisas e trabalhando o tipo correto, mas a maioria só usa porque ele faz um trabalho para garantir que seja colocado de uma forma que evite o *SQL injection*.

Claro que não é a função em si que realiza isso, é todo o mecanismo, ela é a porta de entrada visível.

Em algumas tecnologias ele pode ter alguma ação adicional, o que não é necessariamente uma vantagem, mas no `mysqli` é só isso. Não que seja algo substancial mas no `mysqli` é mais seguro por ser nativo (ao contrário da crença popular que o PDO seria mais seguro).

Comment: Essa questão de colocar o valor na query, se tu coloca tipo: insert into exemplo values ($id,$valor) por exemplo... tem chance de sql injection grande new

Comment: Sim, esse é o principal problema.